# How to edit data of a file File Handling C

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm wondering if I could use `fseek()` on editing the value of a variable on a file. All the tutorials I saw online were about editing a text, but how can I use `fseek()` to edit a value.
Here's how my program works: The user inputs a name, gender, and age. The user can input as many data as they want. Now, the user searches a name; and the gender, and age of that name will display. The user is then prompted to edit the age. After inputting a new age, the file will now be edited, with the new age written.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
char name[30];
char gender[10];
int age;
};

int main(void)
{
struct data client;

FILE* fp;
char ch = 0;
do
{
    printf("Enter Name: ");
    scanf("%s", client.name);

    printf("Enter Gender: ");
    scanf("%s", client.gender);

    printf("Enter Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &client.age);

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "ab");
    fwrite(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("continue? \n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
} while (ch != 'n'); // continuously appends file till letter n is read;

char input[30]; // user input
printf("name?\n"); 
scanf("%s", input);

struct data Read; 
fp = fopen("data.txt", "rb");
int newAge;
while (fread(&client, sizeof(client), 1, fp))
{
    if (strcmp(client.name, input) == 0) // compare variable with user input
    {
        printf("%s", client.name);
        printf("       %s", client.gender);
        printf("      %d y/o", client.age);
        printf("\n");
        printf("enter new age"); 
        scanf("%d", &newAge);

        //fseek function
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: You have a file of "records". Each record is `sizeof(struct data)` bytes long. Look at this file as a kind of array, where each record (element/structure) have a zero-based index. To go to index X then you need to see `X * sizeof(struct data)` bytes into the file from the beginning.

Comment: So, how do I implement it?

Comment: Do I still have to use `fseek()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you provide an example?

Comment: An alternative is to use *memory mapping*, but the APIs are operating system dependant.  On UNIX-type systems see `man mmap`.